# get files from google clous storage without using public url?

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Hope you are doing well .
I’m working currently on a project that gets mp3 content from Google Cloud Storage into a web application to be played for users .
I just wanna know how I can get those audio files on streaming without downloading them in my project repo .
One approach is using a public Url , but I think that is not secure because people who know the url can access all my files stored in the cloud ?
I'm using php laravel

Comment: Generate and use Google Cloud Storage Signed URLs.

Answer (score 1):

The only approach to this case I think is to use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#signed_urls_query_string_authentication) because we don't know whether they have a Google account.

Another solution that download the file locally on the server, and then let the user download the file from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your response , I think that using signed urls will provide me a url to share but can be available just for a specific period. In my project I want users to have unlimited access to some files without knowing the exact url . I think there's an approach where I can use gs://example-bucket/example.mp3(gsutil) in get_file_content function .

Comment: You can use custom proxy (such as Cloud Functions), but nothing out of the box.